# How do I compare sequential characters in two strings with loops?

Tags: python, loops

I have two strings 'hello' and 'leetcode' inside an array words.

I am struggling to compare each of the characters in the string, one by one - so for example, I want to compare

- 'h' with 'l'
- 'e' with 'e'
- 'l' with 'e'
- and so on.

I have written the following for loops below, but they don't seem to do the job, as it prints the wrong result.

```
words = ["hello","leetcode"]

for j in range(len(words)):
    for k in range(len(words[j])):
        if words[j][k] < words[j + 1][k]:
```

Any idea how to amend the above, or suggest another way to do this?

Comment: What does your expected output look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Fix

You need one `for` loop that generates indices for **both** words

```
words = ["hello", "leetcode"]
for j in range(min(len(words[0]), len(words[1]))):
    if words[0][j] < words[1][j]:
        print("LO")
    elif words[0][j] > words[1][j]:
        print("UP")
    elif words[0][j] == words[1][j]:
        print("EQ")
```

---

#### Improve

You can iterate on pair using `zip`, that directly yields chars of each words

```
words = ["hello", "leetcode"]
for c1, c2 in zip(*words):
    if c1 < c2:
        print("LO")
    elif c1 > c2:
        print("UP")
    elif c1 == c2:
        print("EQ")
```

Comment: Thanks Azro, but what if there are more than just two words to compare? Say I still wanted to just compare adjacent words but let's say there are 5, how can I extend the above?

Comment: @hefufhiwh is depends on the action, what do you mean by `compare` ? try `for chars in zip(*words): print(chars)` with more than 2 words in the list, you'll get each list of chars by indices, then do what you need

Comment: This worked, thanks! Can I ask- is there any difference between using zip() and 'for loops'? The complexity will be the same, so is it just aesthetically more pleasing?

Comment: @hefufhiwh I'm not sure about complexity so I won't tell, but that's just easiest. You can't imagine not using zip if you have 10,20, 30... words in your list

Answer (score 1):

I would let Python split out the characters for me:

```
for a, b in zip(*words):
    if a==b:
        print(f"{a}=={b}")
    else:
        print(f"{a}!={b}")

h!=l
e==e
l!=e
l!=t
o!=c
```

If there are more than two words, the technique is the same:

```
>>> words = ["hello","leetcode","hellooo"]
>>> list(zip(words))
>>> [('h', 'l', 'h'), ('e', 'e', 'e'), ('l', 'e', 'l'), ('l', 't', 'l'), ('o', 'c', 'o')]
```

As you can see, this will work for any number of words. But it is unclear what you would then mean by *match*. If you are looking for a match at the same position in all the words, you could do it this way:

```
words = ["hello","leetcode","hellooo"]
for index, mytuple in enumerate(zip(*words)):
    if len(set(mytuple)) == 1:
        print(f"Match on {mytuple[0]} at position {index}")

    
Match on e at position 1
```

Comment: Thanks Boar- but what is there are more than just two words? I still want to compare each adjacent word, could I use the above but iterate through the whole list doing this?

Comment: Answer extended to cover more than 2 words.

Comment: Thanks Boar- I still can't quite understand how to extend it to more words, how does the "for a,b in zip(*words)" change? Because if we have let's say 7 words, would I have to do for a,b,c,d,e,f,g in zip(*words)? Otherwise how can I reference this? Thanks!

Comment: Take another look at the revised answer.  With an unspecified number of words, you can't have individually named variables . That is why the loop puts the letters in `mytuple` instead.